# Converting a series of ints to strings - Why is apply much faster than astype?

Tags: python, string, performance, pandas, python-internals

I have a `pandas.Series` containing integers, but I need to convert these to strings for some downstream tools. So suppose I had a `Series` object:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000000))
```

On StackOverflow and other websites, I've seen most people argue that the best way to do this is:

```
%% timeit
x = x.astype(str)
```

This takes about 2 seconds.

When I use `x = x.apply(str)`, it only takes 0.2 seconds.

Why is `x.astype(str)` so slow? Should the recommended way be `x.apply(str)`?

I'm mainly interested in python 3's behavior for this.

Comment: Still not know the reason , but `list(map(str,x))`, is faster than `x.apply(str)`

Comment: You may be interested in this [meta discussion of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365875/should-we-improve-edit-abandoned-questions); jpp claims you've abandoned this question.

Comment: For anyone answering, please assume Python 3.x as OP has provided no confirmation either way. I have specified Python / Pandas / Numpy versions in my (now community wiki) answer for reference.

Comment: @jpp Yes, I was working with pandas on python 3. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Performance**

It's worth looking at actual performance before beginning any investigation since, contrary to popular opinion, `list(map(str, x))` appears to be *slower* than `x.apply(str)`.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

### Versions: Pandas 0.20.3, Numpy 1.13.1, Python 3.6.2 ###

x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000))

%timeit x.apply(str)          # 42ms   (1)
%timeit x.map(str)            # 42ms   (2)
%timeit x.astype(str)         # 559ms  (3)
%timeit [str(i) for i in x]   # 566ms  (4)
%timeit list(map(str, x))     # 536ms  (5)
%timeit x.values.astype(str)  # 25ms   (6)
```

Points worth noting:

1. (5) is marginally quicker than (3) / (4), which we expect as more work is moved into C [assuming no `lambda` function is used].
2. (6) is by far the fastest.
3. (1) / (2) are similar.
4. (3) / (4) are similar.

**Why is x.map / x.apply fast?**

This *appears to be* because it uses fast [compiled Cython code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/699a48bcd71da54da05caee85e5d006afabc3df6/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L473-L483):

```
cpdef ndarray[object] astype_str(ndarray arr):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n = arr.size
        ndarray[object] result = np.empty(n, dtype=object)

    for i in range(n):
        # we can use the unsafe version because we know `result` is mutable
        # since it was created from `np.empty`
        util.set_value_at_unsafe(result, i, str(arr[i]))

    return result
```

**Why is x.astype(str) slow?**

Pandas applies `str` to each item in the series, not using the above Cython.

Hence performance is comparable to `[str(i) for i in x]` / `list(map(str, x))`.

**Why is x.values.astype(str) so fast?**

Numpy does not apply a function on each element of the array. [One description](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8732) of this I found:

> If you did `s.values.astype(str)` what you get back is an object holding
>   `int`. This is `numpy` doing the conversion, whereas pandas iterates over
>   each item and calls `str(item)` on it. So if you do `s.astype(str)` you have
>   an object holding `str`.

There is a technical reason [why the numpy version hasn't been implemented](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/8971) in the case of no-nulls.

Comment: You probably want to denote what version of NumPy, Pandas, Python you are benchmarking on, as well as your computer specs. Otherwise this isn't really meaningful. For instance, w/ NumPy 1.14.1, Pandas 0.22.0, Python 3.6.4, also benchmarking with `%timeit`, `x.apply(str)` takes 18ms and `list(map(str, x))` takes 15ms for me with your sample data. The benchmark order is completely different.

Comment: My initial impression, though, is that this has a lot more to do with the dtypes of NumPy string arrays (unicode) vs the dtype of Pandas str columns (object).

Comment: Yes, `x.values.astype(str)` returns type `<U11`, so not Python byte-code `str`. But I couldn't confirm `x.map(str)` verus `x.astype(str)` discrepancy via source code.

Comment: @miradulo, added versions to test code; also converted to wiki so others are invited to contribute.

Comment: A function named `astype_str` sure sounds like it would be used for `astype(str)`, not for `map` or `apply`.

Comment: @user2357112, you might be right. A while back I turned this into a community wiki to encourage those better versed in C to follow the code. This is just my manual digging (may need checking).

Comment: @miradulo, Commenting to bring this bounty to your attention. As you looked at this briefly before.

Comment: @jpp Yeah, I looked at this last night a bit. I might write up an answer if I come to understand a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788058/performance-hit-in-int-to-string-conversion-but-an-object-pit-stop-avoids-it) I asked about last night :)

Answer (score 27):

Let's begin with a bit of general advise: If you're interested in finding the bottlenecks of Python code you can use a profiler to find the functions/parts that eat up most of the time. In this case I use a line-profiler because you can actually see the implementation and the time spent on each line.

However, these tools don't work with C or Cython by default. Given that CPython (that's the Python interpreter I'm using), NumPy and pandas make heavy use of C and Cython there will be a limit how far I'll get with profiling.

Actually: one probably could extend profiling to the Cython code and probably also the C code by recompiling it with debug symbols and tracing, however it's not an easy task to compile these libraries so I won't do that (but if someone likes to do that the [Cython documentation includes a page about profiling Cython code](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html)).

But let's see how far I can get:

### Line-Profiling Python code

I'm going to use [line-profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) and a Jupyter Notebook here:

```
%load_ext line_profiler

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000))
```

#### Profiling `x.astype`

```
%lprun -f x.astype x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    87                                                   @wraps(func)
    88                                                   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    89         1           12     12.0      0.0              old_arg_value = kwargs.pop(old_arg_name, None)
    90         1            5      5.0      0.0              if old_arg_value is not None:
    91                                                           if mapping is not None:
   ...
   118         1       663354 663354.0    100.0              return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

So that's simply a decorator and 100% of the time is spent in the decorated function. So let's profile the decorated function:

```
%lprun -f x.astype.__wrapped__ x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  3896                                               @deprecate_kwarg(old_arg_name='raise_on_error', new_arg_name='errors',
  3897                                                                mapping={True: 'raise', False: 'ignore'})
  3898                                               def astype(self, dtype, copy=True, errors='raise', **kwargs):
  3899                                                   """
  ...
  3975                                                   """
  3976         1           28     28.0      0.0          if is_dict_like(dtype):
  3977                                                       if self.ndim == 1:  # i.e. Series
  ...
  4001                                           
  4002                                                   # else, only a single dtype is given
  4003         1           14     14.0      0.0          new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
  4004         1       685863 685863.0     99.9                                       **kwargs)
  4005         1          340    340.0      0.0          return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L3896-L4005)

Again one line is the bottleneck so let's check the `_data.astype` method:

```
%lprun -f x._data.astype x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  3461                                               def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
  3462         1       695866 695866.0    100.0          return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
```

Okay, another delegate, let's see what `_data.apply` does:

```
%lprun -f x._data.apply x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  3251                                               def apply(self, f, axes=None, filter=None, do_integrity_check=False,
  3252                                                         consolidate=True, **kwargs):
  3253                                                   """
  ...
  3271                                                   """
  3272                                           
  3273         1           12     12.0      0.0          result_blocks = []
  ...
  3309                                           
  3310         1           10     10.0      0.0          aligned_args = dict((k, kwargs[k])
  3311         1           29     29.0      0.0                              for k in align_keys
  3312                                                                       if hasattr(kwargs[k], 'reindex_axis'))
  3313                                           
  3314         2           28     14.0      0.0          for b in self.blocks:
  ...
  3329         1       674974 674974.0    100.0              applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  3330         1           30     30.0      0.0              result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
  3331                                           
  3332         1           10     10.0      0.0          if len(result_blocks) == 0:
  3333                                                       return self.make_empty(axes or self.axes)
  3334         1           10     10.0      0.0          bm = self.__class__(result_blocks, axes or self.axes,
  3335         1           76     76.0      0.0                              do_integrity_check=do_integrity_check)
  3336         1           13     13.0      0.0          bm._consolidate_inplace()
  3337         1            7      7.0      0.0          return bm
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/internals.py#L3251-L3337)

And again ... one function call is taking all the time, this time it's `x._data.blocks[0].astype`:

```
%lprun -f x._data.blocks[0].astype x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   542                                               def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
   543         1           18     18.0      0.0          return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
   544         1       671092 671092.0    100.0                              **kwargs)
```

.. which is another delegate...

```
%lprun -f x._data.blocks[0]._astype x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   546                                               def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,
   547                                                           klass=None, mgr=None, **kwargs):
   548                                                   """
   ...
   557                                                   """
   558         1           11     11.0      0.0          errors_legal_values = ('raise', 'ignore')
   559                                           
   560         1            8      8.0      0.0          if errors not in errors_legal_values:
   561                                                       invalid_arg = ("Expected value of kwarg 'errors' to be one of {}. "
   562                                                                      "Supplied value is '{}'".format(
   563                                                                          list(errors_legal_values), errors))
   564                                                       raise ValueError(invalid_arg)
   565                                           
   566         1           23     23.0      0.0          if inspect.isclass(dtype) and issubclass(dtype, ExtensionDtype):
   567                                                       msg = ("Expected an instance of {}, but got the class instead. "
   568                                                              "Try instantiating 'dtype'.".format(dtype.__name__))
   569                                                       raise TypeError(msg)
   570                                           
   571                                                   # may need to convert to categorical
   572                                                   # this is only called for non-categoricals
   573         1           72     72.0      0.0          if self.is_categorical_astype(dtype):
   ...
   595                                           
   596                                                   # astype processing
   597         1           16     16.0      0.0          dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
   598         1           19     19.0      0.0          if self.dtype == dtype:
   ...
   603         1            8      8.0      0.0          if klass is None:
   604         1           13     13.0      0.0              if dtype == np.object_:
   605                                                           klass = ObjectBlock
   606         1            6      6.0      0.0          try:
   607                                                       # force the copy here
   608         1            7      7.0      0.0              if values is None:
   609                                           
   610         1            8      8.0      0.0                  if issubclass(dtype.type,
   611         1           14     14.0      0.0                                (compat.text_type, compat.string_types)):
   612                                           
   613                                                               # use native type formatting for datetime/tz/timedelta
   614         1           15     15.0      0.0                      if self.is_datelike:
   615                                                                   values = self.to_native_types()
   616                                           
   617                                                               # astype formatting
   618                                                               else:
   619         1            8      8.0      0.0                          values = self.values
   620                                           
   621                                                           else:
   622                                                               values = self.get_values(dtype=dtype)
   623                                           
   624                                                           # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
   625         1       665777 665777.0     99.9                  values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
   626         1           32     32.0      0.0                  values = values.reshape(self.shape)
   627                                           
   628         1           17     17.0      0.0              newb = make_block(values, placement=self.mgr_locs, dtype=dtype,
   629         1          269    269.0      0.0                                klass=klass)
   630                                                   except:
   631                                                       if errors == 'raise':
   632                                                           raise
   633                                                       newb = self.copy() if copy else self
   634                                           
   635         1            8      8.0      0.0          if newb.is_numeric and self.is_numeric:
   ...
   642         1            6      6.0      0.0          return newb
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/internals.py#L546-L642)

... okay, still not there. Let's check out `astype_nansafe`:

```
%lprun -f pd.core.internals.astype_nansafe x.astype(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   640                                           def astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy=True):
   641                                               """ return a view if copy is False, but
   642                                                   need to be very careful as the result shape could change! """
   643         1           13     13.0      0.0      if not isinstance(dtype, np.dtype):
   644                                                   dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
   645                                           
   646         1            8      8.0      0.0      if issubclass(dtype.type, text_type):
   647                                                   # in Py3 that's str, in Py2 that's unicode
   648         1       663317 663317.0    100.0          return lib.astype_unicode(arr.ravel()).reshape(arr.shape)
   ...
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py#L640-L704)

Again one it's one line that takes 100%, so I'll go one function further:

```
%lprun -f pd.core.dtypes.cast.lib.astype_unicode x.astype(str)

UserWarning: Could not extract a code object for the object <built-in function astype_unicode>
```

Okay, we found a `built-in function`, that means it's a C function. In this case it's a Cython function. But it means we cannot dig deeper with line-profiler. So I'll stop here for now.

#### Profiling `x.apply`

```
%lprun -f x.apply x.apply(str)
```

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  2426                                               def apply(self, func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwds):
  2427                                                   """
  ...
  2523                                                   """
  2524         1           84     84.0      0.0          if len(self) == 0:
  2525                                                       return self._constructor(dtype=self.dtype,
  2526                                                                                index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
  2527                                           
  2528                                                   # dispatch to agg
  2529         1           11     11.0      0.0          if isinstance(func, (list, dict)):
  2530                                                       return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwds)
  2531                                           
  2532                                                   # if we are a string, try to dispatch
  2533         1           12     12.0      0.0          if isinstance(func, compat.string_types):
  2534                                                       return self._try_aggregate_string_function(func, *args, **kwds)
  2535                                           
  2536                                                   # handle ufuncs and lambdas
  2537         1            7      7.0      0.0          if kwds or args and not isinstance(func, np.ufunc):
  2538                                                       f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwds)
  2539                                                   else:
  2540         1            6      6.0      0.0              f = func
  2541                                           
  2542         1          154    154.0      0.1          with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
  2543         1           11     11.0      0.0              if isinstance(f, np.ufunc):
  2544                                                           return f(self)
  2545                                           
  2546                                                       # row-wise access
  2547         1          188    188.0      0.1              if is_extension_type(self.dtype):
  2548                                                           mapped = self._values.map(f)
  2549                                                       else:
  2550         1         6238   6238.0      3.3                  values = self.asobject
  2551         1       181910 181910.0     95.5                  mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  2552                                           
  2553         1           28     28.0      0.0          if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
  2554                                                       from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  2555                                                       return DataFrame(mapped.tolist(), index=self.index)
  2556                                                   else:
  2557         1           19     19.0      0.0              return self._constructor(mapped,
  2558         1         1870   1870.0      1.0                                       index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/series.py#L2426-L2558)

Again it's one function that takes most of the time: `lib.map_infer` ...

```
%lprun -f pd.core.series.lib.map_infer x.apply(str)
```

```
Could not extract a code object for the object <built-in function map_infer>
```

Okay, that's another Cython function.

This time there's another (although less significant) contributor with ~3%: `values = self.asobject`. But I'll ignore this for now, because we're interested in the major contributors.

### Going into C/Cython

#### The functions called by `astype`

This is the `astype_unicode` function:

```
cpdef ndarray[object] astype_unicode(ndarray arr):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n = arr.size
        ndarray[object] result = np.empty(n, dtype=object)

    for i in range(n):
        # we can use the unsafe version because we know `result` is mutable
        # since it was created from `np.empty`
        util.set_value_at_unsafe(result, i, unicode(arr[i]))

    return result
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L859-L869)

This function uses this helper:

```cython
cdef inline set_value_at_unsafe(ndarray arr, object loc, object value):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, sz
    if is_float_object(loc):
        casted = int(loc)
        if casted == loc:
            loc = casted
    i = <Py_ssize_t> loc
    sz = cnp.PyArray_SIZE(arr)

    if i < 0:
        i += sz
    elif i >= sz:
        raise IndexError('index out of bounds')

    assign_value_1d(arr, i, value)
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/src/util.pxd#L71-L91)

Which itself uses this C function:

```c
PANDAS_INLINE int assign_value_1d(PyArrayObject* ap, Py_ssize_t _i,
                                  PyObject* v) {
    npy_intp i = (npy_intp)_i;
    char* item = (char*)PyArray_DATA(ap) + i * PyArray_STRIDE(ap, 0);
    return PyArray_DESCR(ap)->f->setitem(v, item, ap);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/src/numpy_helper.h#L56-L61)

#### Functions called by `apply`

This is the implementation of the `map_infer` function:

```cython
def map_infer(ndarray arr, object f, bint convert=1):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, n
        ndarray[object] result
        object val

    n = len(arr)
    result = np.empty(n, dtype=object)
    for i in range(n):
        val = f(util.get_value_at(arr, i))

        # unbox 0-dim arrays, GH #690
        if is_array(val) and PyArray_NDIM(val) == 0:
            # is there a faster way to unbox?
            val = val.item()

        result[i] = val

    if convert:
        return maybe_convert_objects(result,
                                     try_float=0,
                                     convert_datetime=0,
                                     convert_timedelta=0)

    return result
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/src/inference.pyx#L1457-L1497)

With this helper:

```cython
cdef inline object get_value_at(ndarray arr, object loc):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, sz
        int casted

    if is_float_object(loc):
        casted = int(loc)
        if casted == loc:
            loc = casted
    i = <Py_ssize_t> loc
    sz = cnp.PyArray_SIZE(arr)

    if i < 0 and sz > 0:
        i += sz
    elif i >= sz or sz == 0:
        raise IndexError('index out of bounds')

    return get_value_1d(arr, i)
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/index.pyx#L45-L50)

Which uses this C function:

```c
PANDAS_INLINE PyObject* get_value_1d(PyArrayObject* ap, Py_ssize_t i) {
    char* item = (char*)PyArray_DATA(ap) + i * PyArray_STRIDE(ap, 0);
    return PyArray_Scalar(item, PyArray_DESCR(ap), (PyObject*)ap);
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/_libs/src/numpy_helper.h#L63-L66)

#### Some thoughts on the Cython code

There are some differences between the Cython codes that are called eventually.

The one taken by `astype` uses `unicode` while the `apply` path uses the function passed in. Let's see if that makes a difference (again IPython/Jupyter makes it very easy to compile Cython code yourself):

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef object func_called_by_astype(np.ndarray arr):
    cdef np.ndarray[object] ret = np.empty(arr.size, dtype=object)
    for i in range(arr.size):
        ret[i] = unicode(arr[i])
    return ret

cpdef object func_called_by_apply(np.ndarray arr, object f):
    cdef np.ndarray[object] ret = np.empty(arr.size, dtype=object)
    for i in range(arr.size):
        ret[i] = f(arr[i])
    return ret
```

Timing:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000000)
%timeit func_called_by_astype(arr)
514 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit func_called_by_apply(arr, str)
632 ms ± 43.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Okay, there is a difference but it's *wrong*, it would actually indicate that `apply` would be slightly **slower**.

But remember the `asobject` call that I mentioned earlier in the `apply` function? Could that be the reason? Let's see:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10000, 1000000)
%timeit func_called_by_astype(arr)
557 ms ± 33.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit func_called_by_apply(arr.astype(object), str)
317 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Now it looks better. The conversion to an object array made the function called by apply much faster. There is a simple reason for this: `str` is a Python function and these are generally much faster if you already have Python objects and NumPy (or Pandas) don't need to create a Python wrapper for the value stored in the array (which is generally not a Python object, except when the array is of dtype `object`).

However that doesn't explain the **huge** difference that you've seen. My suspicion is that there is actually an additional difference in the ways the arrays are iterated over and the elements are set in the result. Very likely the:

```
val = f(util.get_value_at(arr, i))
if is_array(val) and PyArray_NDIM(val) == 0:
    val = val.item()
result[i] = val
```

part of the `map_infer` function is faster than:

```
for i in range(n):
    # we can use the unsafe version because we know `result` is mutable
    # since it was created from `np.empty`
    util.set_value_at_unsafe(result, i, unicode(arr[i]))
```

which is called by the `astype(str)` path. The comments of the first function seem to indicate that the writer of `map_infer` actually tried to make the code as fast as possible (see the comment about "is there a faster way to unbox?" while the other one maybe was written without special care about performance. But that's just a guess.

Also on my computer I'm actually quite close to the performance of the `x.astype(str)` and `x.apply(str)` already:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000000)
s = pd.Series(arr)
%timeit s.astype(str)
535 ms ± 23.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit func_called_by_astype(arr)
547 ms ± 21.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%timeit s.apply(str)
216 ms ± 8.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit func_called_by_apply(arr.astype(object), str)
272 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Note that I also checked some other variants that return a different result:

```
%timeit s.values.astype(str)  # array of strings
407 ms ± 8.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit list(map(str, s.values.tolist()))  # list of strings
184 ms ± 5.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Interestingly the Python loop with `list` and `map` seems to be the fastest on my computer.

I actually made a small benchmark including plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import simple_benchmark

def Series_astype(series):
    return series.astype(str)

def Series_apply(series):
    return series.apply(str)

def Series_tolist_map(series):
    return list(map(str, series.values.tolist()))

def Series_values_astype(series):
    return series.values.astype(str)


arguments = {2**i: pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 2**i)) for i in range(2, 20)}
b = simple_benchmark.benchmark(
    [Series_astype, Series_apply, Series_tolist_map, Series_values_astype],
    arguments,
    argument_name='Series size'
)

%matplotlib notebook
b.plot()
```

[image]

Note that it's a log-log plot because of the huge range of sizes I covered in the benchmark. However lower means faster here.

The results may be different for different versions of Python/NumPy/Pandas. So if you want to compare it, these are my versions:

```
Versions
--------
Python 3.6.5
NumPy 1.14.2
Pandas 0.22.0
```

Comment: Excellent detail into the internals, I never considered line profiling. Can you please provide the version numbers of Python / Numpy / Pandas you are using?

Comment: @jpp I added the versions and also links to the source code (at least for the non-trivial functions). Yeah, line-profiling is great as long as it's pure Python code. But it becomes really complicated with Cython/C code.