# Performance hit in int to string conversion, but an object pit stop avoids it

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy

Given a NumPy array of integral type

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10**6)
```

why is it (now) faster to take a trip through the `object` dtype before casting to string? This holds for all integral types. (note this doesn't produce exactly the same type, `'<U2'` instead of `'<U21'`)

```
>>> %timeit arr.astype(str)
506 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit arr.astype(object).astype(str)
161 ms ± 1.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It also only seems to be true as of NumPy `1.14.0` - here's the same benchmarks in `1.13.3`.

```
>>> %timeit arr.astype(str)
119 ms ± 280 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

>>> %timeit arr.astype(object).astype(str)
164 ms ± 207 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is the string cast handling some previously existing bug or whatnot now?

---

I tried to look around in the changes to [numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c) and the [1.14 release notes](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.14.0-notes.rst), but haven't noticed anything yet.

Python version: `3.6.4`

Comment: Actually, they don't produce the same result. `dtype`s are different

Comment: @PaulPanzer Ah correct, question remains the same to me though.

Comment: The dtype thing is a red herring.  Can reproduce (3.6.0 / 1.14.0 / macOS).

Comment: It seems likely that NumPy 1.14's many changes to print formatting might have something to do with it.

Comment: @wim yeah, forcing `'U21'` in both cases indeed doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user2357112 Agreed, that was what struck me as potentially relevant.