# Combine columns of different types in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0.2, 0.3, .5], 'col2':['a', 'b', 'c']})
```

And I want to obtain a third column col3 which would be something like:

```
{'col1':['20% a', '30% b, '50% c']}
```

Is there anyway of solving this without iterating each row of the DataFrame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0.2, 0.3, .5], 'col2':['a', 'b', 'c']})

df['col3'] = (df['col1']*100).astype(int).apply(str) + '% ' + df['col2']

print(df)

   col1 col2   col3
0   0.2    a  20% a
1   0.3    b  30% b
2   0.5    c  50% c
```

As @JonClements points out, you can use `lambda` with string formatting, but I have an allergy to them.. only good [in small doses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749018/why-is-pandas-apply-lambda-slower-than-loop-here):

```
df['cole'] = df.apply(lambda r: f'{r.col1 * 100}% {r.col2}', 1)
```

Comment: But haven't we learned that using `apply(str)` is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371629/converting-a-series-of-ints-to-strings-why-is-apply-much-faster-than-astype)? :-)

Comment: @pault, Yes, that's true :). Still haven't got a C-level explanation though!

Comment: One could also do: `df.apply(lambda r: f'{r.col1 * 100}% {r.col2}', 1)` (slightly slower though)