# pandas to_datetime() not detecting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns(h1, h2, h3) representing day, month and year respectively, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'h1': [1,2,3],
    'h2': [1,2,3],
    'h3': [2000,2001,2002]
})
```

when i perform:

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['h1', 'h2', 'h3']])
```

this result into an error: `ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`  but when i rename the columns and then perform the pd.to_datetime e.g

```
df=df.rename(columns ={'h1':'day', 'h2':'month', 'h3': 'year'})
df["date_col"] =pd.to_datetime(df[['day','month','year']])
```

on it I get the year column, Do we have to be doing it this way? or is it possible to provide a format so that the columns can be detected as day, month , year respectively?
Thanks.

Comment: create date from those three columns(h1, h2, h3) using pandas library to_datetime method

Comment: Sure, It works fine but I do not want to rename columns before I create it

Comment: Great, Thanks. This comprehension works fine.

Comment: I have formatted your question in a way I think is more readable. I also removed some parts of my answer as they were mere copies. Hope you find it more readable as I do and maybe apply it in the future :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Summing up:

Your approach with renaming the columns is already smart as the docs says:

> Examples
>
> Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys
> can be common abbreviations like [‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’, ‘minute’,
> ‘second’, ‘ms’, ‘us’, ‘ns’]) or plurals of the same

But there are some alternatives. In my experience the list comprehension using zip is quite fast (for small sets). With around 3000 rows of data renaming the columns becomes the quickest. Looking at the graph the penalty for renaming is hard for small set but compensates for large ones.

#### Alternatives

```
pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(map(str,i)) for i in zip(df['h3'],df['h2'],df['h1'])])
pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(i) for i in df[['h3', 'h2', 'h1']].values.astype(str)])
df[['h3','h2','h1']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime('-'.join(x)), 1)
pd.to_datetime(df[['h1','h2','h3']].rename(columns={'h1':'day', 'h2':'month','h3':'year'}))
```

#### Timings Win10:

```
#df = pd.concat([df]*1000)
2.74 ms ± 33.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
8.08 ms ± 158 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
158 ms ± 472 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.64 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### Timings MacBook Air:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 6.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 335 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.7 ms per loop
```

---

**Update** with code I wrote (happy if you have suggestions to improve or any library that could help):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'h1': np.arange(1,11),
    'h2': np.arange(1,11),
    'h3': np.arange(2000,2010)
})

myfuncs = {
"pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(map(str,i)) for i in zip(df['h3'],df['h2'],df['h1'])])":
    lambda: pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(map(str,i)) for i in zip(df['h3'],df['h2'],df['h1'])]),
"pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(i) for i in df[['h3','h2', 'h1']].values.astype(str)])":
    lambda: pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(i) for i in df[['h3','h2', 'h1']].values.astype(str)]),
"pd.to_datetime(df[['h1','h2','h3']].rename(columns={'h1':'day','h2':'month','h3':'year'}))":
    lambda: pd.to_datetime(df[['h1','h2','h3']].rename(columns={'h1':'day','h2':'month','h3':'year'}))
}

d = defaultdict(dict)
step = 10
cont = True
while cont:
    lendf = len(df); print(lendf)
    for k,v in mycodes.items():
        iters = 1
        t = 0
        while t < 0.2:
            ts = timeit.repeat(v, number=iters, repeat=3)
            t = min(ts)
            iters *= 10
        d[k][lendf] = t/iters
        if t > 2: cont = False
    df = pd.concat([df]*step)

pd.DataFrame(d).plot().legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15))
plt.yscale('log'); plt.xscale('log'); plt.ylabel('seconds'); plt.xlabel('df rows')
plt.show()
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Even faster: `pd.to_datetime(['-'.join(i) for i in df[['h3', 'h2', 'h1']].values.astype(str)])`; inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49804868/9209546).

Comment: @jpp Nice link, however I dont get those results. It is about 3x slower. with my timings

Comment: Yes that is indeed strange. maybe a 3rd person could enlighten us! :) I posted the code I am running

Comment: For reference, I see `53.1ms / 20.5ms / 500ms / 7.85ms` with your exact code; renaming still the best. But the first vs second have v different relative performance; Dual-core 2.5GHz, Win7, 4GB memory, pandas 0.20.3, python 3.6.2

Comment: @jpp Interesting. I am running i7 6700 on Win10, 16GB ddr4. Also tried it on my macbook (OSX)

Comment: @jpp what do you think of the function I added?

Comment: @jezrael Actually it is this code I am trying to improve.

Comment: @AntonvBR - thanks, what about use [`perplots`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389889/2901002)?

Comment: @jezrael Interesting, it is similar.

Comment: I don't understand the performance angle? Was that in an old version of the question?